# Bind two embeddings in a number field together

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, algebraic-number-theory

Let $K$ be a totally real number field (over $\mathbb Q$), and let $\sigma_1,\dots, \sigma_r$ be all $r$ (real) embeddings of $K$. Consider the subfield:

$$L:= \{a\in K: \sigma_1(a)= \sigma_2(a)\}$$

I wonder if $L$ now has $r-1$ real embeddings (doesn't have to be $\sigma_2, \dots, \sigma_r$, restricted to $L$, forming $r-1$ distinct real embeddings of L). I believe this is at least true for quadratic extensions.

Comment: Essentially your $L$ is the fixed field of the subgroup generated by $\sigma_1 \sigma_2^{-1}$. So the conclusion depends on the order/index of this subgroup.

Comment: You should try an example with $K=\mathbb{Q} (\sqrt {2+\sqrt{2}})$.

Comment: Maybe I've mistunderstood your question, but I don't think this can ever be true if $K$ is not quadratic. $L$ has at most $[L:\mathbb Q]$ real embeddings.... but if $L$ is a proper subfield of the degree $r$ field $K$, then $[L:\mathbb Q]\le \frac r2 < r-1$ if $r>2$.

Comment: @Mathmo123: good catch. The index of a proper subgroup is at least $2$ so $[K:L] \geq 2$.